# Flutter: Is possible to sending request to server (position data) every 5 minutes in background (Android and iOS)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on some kind of Safety Application. Now I'm stuck with this problem: I need to send request (position data) from application to server side every 5 minutes. Is possible done this on Flutter side or only via native code? If yes share this idea with me please.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Good news, but how? Some Plugin or there MUST be native code?

Answer (score 2):

Try using timer

```
final a = Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 5), (tick) {
          // Write your code here.....
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Check out this plugin [background_fetch 0.3.1](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch)

It will make it easier for you to run dart code in the background,
but this plugin only allows background tasks every 15 minutes.

> There is no way to increase the rate which a fetch-event occurs and this plugin sets the rate to the most frequent possible — you will never receive an event faster than 15 minutes. The operating-system will automatically throttle the rate the background-fetch events occur based upon usage patterns. Eg: if user hasn't turned on their phone for a long period of time, fetch events will occur less frequently.

To add this plugin to your application, follow the [Installing the plugin guide](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch#large_blue_diamond-installing-the-plugin).